# Why the event $X$ intersected by $Y$, is equal to $Y$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

A die is thrown until the number 3 appears:

- $X$ is the event "In the first thrown I do not get the number 3"
- $Y$ is the event "In the first four thrown I do not get the number 3"
- $(X∩Y) = Y $

**Why?**

Comment: To not roll a 3 in the first 4 rolls you need to not roll a 3 on the first roll.

Comment: $X\cap Y$ is different from $Y$ if it is possible to satisfy $Y$ while not satisfying $X$. Can you see that this is not possible in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is not very precise, but $X\cap Y$ is the event "both $X$ and $Y$ happen". This means that "I do not get number 3 on the first thrown" AND "I do not get number 3 on the first four thrown", which is equivalent to say "I do not get number 3 on the first four thrown", which is $Y$.

Comment: Whenever **Y->X** then **(X∩Y)=Y**?

Comment: Yes, you can write $Y\Rightarrow X$ as $Y\subseteq X$ in your notation

Answer (score 4):

Note that $X\cap Y=Y$ if and only if $Y\subset X$.